# download files outside the document root using PHP

Tags: get, php

I'm trying to download a file using readfile(); in PHP but I'm having trouble, here's my code:

```
<?php
$getdir = $_GET['dir'];
$getdoctype = $_GET['doctype'];
$getfile = $_GET['filename'];
$dir = "/var/www/uploads/$getdir/$getdoctype/";

$type = mime_content_type( $dir . '/' . $getfile );
$contents = file_get_contents($dir . '/' . $getfile);

if (file_exists($getfile)) {
   header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $getfile);
   readfile($getfile);
}
else{
   echo "File Not Found";
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong? I want to download the file thats stored in $getfile variable. I want to use all filetypes and all filesizes so thats why I did it like this.

The error I keep getting when I click on the file is: "File Not Found" as per my code. But it does exist.

Please also keep in mind that the website that host these files is SSL enabled

Comment: `file_exists($dir . '/' . $getfile)` and `readfile($dir . '/' . $getfile);`  You need to actually read the file you're trying to get.  Also, add the `mime_content_type` call *inside* the `if` and lose the `file_get_contents` call.  Also be careful with using `$_GET` to download files.  What if I send `dir=../../../etc/fstab`?

Comment: Be careful of something like `yourwebsite.com?filename=../../../../database.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try replace this code:

`file_exists($getfile)` => `file_exists($dir . '/' . $getfile)`

`readfile($getfile);` => `readfile($dir . '/' . $getfile);`

But it's very dangerous use `$_GET` parameters to load file from filesystem, don't use this code on public website.

Comment: Thanks and the GET variables don't store full URL paths, they only store one value so it would be use less to a hacker.

Comment: BTW, out of curiousity how would I make the GET variables more safe. The site has a login system but to be on the safe side what else can I do?

Comment: Try to check `$getdir`, `$getdoctype` and `$getfile` variables content before using it. For example: `if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $getdir) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $getdoctype) || !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $getfile)) { die('Bad parameter!'); }`

Answer (score 1):

Your not pointing to the file correctly.

```
<?php
$getdir = $_GET['dir'];
$getdoctype = $_GET['doctype'];
$getfile = $_GET['filename'];
$dir = "/var/www/uploads/$getdir/$getdoctype/";

if (file_exists($dir . $getfile)) {
$type = mime_content_type( $dir . $getfile );
header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $getfile);
readfile($dir . $getfile);
}
else{
echo "File Not Found";
}
?>
```